# Is setting .delegate = self is a property injection?

Tags: ios, swift

I have Custom Class UIViewController with conformed to protocol UITableViewDataSource and Delegate. My questions is, setting my Custom Class as a delegate is called Property Injection? I'm still learning and I think its a property injection since it assigns an Instance of the current class which is self to the tableView, and the `.delegate` is a property.

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Please check https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/dependency-injection-in-swift-87c748a167be#:~:text=Dependency%20Injection%20is%20often%20used%20with%20the%20intention%20of%20writing,and%20thus%2C%20easier%20to%20test.&text=This%20kind%20of%20dependency%20injection,through%20its%20constructor%2C%20or%20initializer.

Comment: If anything else you want to ask Please clear your question.

Comment: thanks for the reference material, same information that I've read before. I don't want to make my own judgement so I'm asking here if its right or wrong, that the `tableView.delegate = self` is an example of a property injection? `self` instance assigned to tableView.delegate property.

Comment: Yes `self` instance assigned to tableView.delegate property is property injection

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct and upvote . Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't upvote since its a new account, will be back after i get required repu.

Comment: Not upvote but u can mark my Answer as correct. Click on Tick in My Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `self` instance assigned to `tableView.delegate` property is **property injection**.
For more you can [Visit here..](https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/dependency-injection-in-swift-87c748a167be#:%7E:text=Dependency%20Injection%20is%20often%20used%20with%20the%20intention%20of%20writing,and%20thus%2C%20easier%20to%20test.&text=This%20kind%20of%20dependency%20injection,through%20its%20constructor%2C%20or%20initializer)